# Kendo UI Core - Upload - How to call MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am using Kendo UI Core (Free version) and would like to upload files to Web Server (through MVC Controller). I know the way with paid Kendo UI version but I want to do it with free version of this.

See as below

HTML For Kendo UI Upload

```
<div class="demo-section k-header">
<input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
</div>
```

Java Script

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: "save",
        removeUrl: "remove",
        autoUpload: true
    }

});
```

It adds a button as below:
[image]

Now Once I select files I want to upload it to server through MVC Controller.

How I should make a call to MVC controller from here?

Cheers

Comment: correct way to use kendo file upload is this...http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/index

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**For Kendo UI Core(as per your question calling controller action to upload files) :-**

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
async: {
    saveUrl: "controllername/actionname",    //OR// '@Url.Action("actionname", "controllername")'   
    removeUrl: "controllername/actionname",  //OR// '@Url.Action("actionname", "controllername")'
    autoUpload: true
  }
});
```

**For example if Controller and Action name is `Upload` and `Save` for Saving and for removing uploaded files Controller and Action name is `Upload` and `Remove` then :-**

```
 $("#files").kendoUpload({
 async: {
    saveUrl: "Upload/Save",     //OR// '@Url.Action("Save", "Upload")'
    removeUrl: "Upload/Remove", //OR// '@Url.Action("Remove", "Upload")'
    autoUpload: true
  }
});
```

---

**A Small Demo of Kendo file Upload(for kendo ui web) :-**

### View :-

```
<form method="post" action='@Url.Action("Submit")' style="width:45%">
    <div class="demo-section">
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
        )
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="k-button" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

### Controller :-

```
 public ActionResult Submit(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (files != null)
        {
            TempData["UploadedFiles"] = GetFileInfo(files);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

 private IEnumerable<string> GetFileInfo(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        return
            from a in files
            where a != null
            select string.Format("{0} ({1} bytes)", Path.GetFileName(a.FileName), a.ContentLength);
    }
```

Complete Documentation is here :- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/index

---

**For Async file Upload :-**

### View :-

```
<div style="width:45%">
    <div class="demo-section">
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
            .Async(a => a
                .Save("Save", "Upload")
                .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
                .AutoUpload(true)
            )
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

### Controller :-

```
 public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    // Some browsers send file names with full path.
                    // We are only interested in the file name.
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

                    // The files are not actually saved in this demo
                    // file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                }
            }

            // Return an empty string to signify success
            return Content("");
        }

        public ActionResult Remove(string[] fileNames)
        {
            // The parameter of the Remove action must be called "fileNames"

            if (fileNames != null)
            {
                foreach (var fullName in fileNames)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullName);
                    var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

                    // TODO: Verify user permissions

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
                    {
                        // The files are not actually removed in this demo
                        // System.IO.File.Delete(physicalPath);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return an empty string to signify success
            return Content("");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Exception. It looks quite good. I will give it a try today and update answer. Cheer

Comment: Unfortunately it did not

Comment: @user2739418...my answer is same as you have given...in my answer upload is controller name and in your answer its Home...'@Url.Action("Save", "Home")'...is same as /Home/Save...

Comment: @user2739418...url generated by '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")'...will be '/Home/Save' as i mentioned in my answer...but the difference is that in your case controller is home and in my answer its upload as i had taken a hypothetical controller and action name because it was not given in your question...

Answer (score 2):

I had a bit of a "Duh" moment with this and realized that if you do not Specify a .SaveField property, then the Name of the control has to be the same as the parameter on the Controller.

Code on .cshtml page with SaveField:

```
Html.Kendo().Upload()
     .Multiple(false)
     .Name("controlName")
     .Async(a => a
         .Save("SavePhoto", "Upload")
         .AutoUpload(true)
         .SaveField("fileParameter")
     );
```

Sample controller:

```
public ActionResult SavePhoto(IFormFile fileParameter)
```

If you leave out the SaveLoad:

```
Html.Kendo().Upload()
     .Multiple(false)
     .Name("uploadFiles")
     .Async(a => a
         .Save("SavePhoto", "Upload")
         .AutoUpload(true)             
     );
```

It will not work.
In this case the name of the control must match the parameter in the controller:

```
public ActionResult SavePhoto(IFormFile uploadFiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set up your wrappers to save time**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload().HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "width:300px;" })
    .Name("upImport")
    .Messages(e => e.DropFilesHere("Drop files here").Select("Select file"))
    .Multiple(false)

    .Async(a => a
        .Save("UploadFile", "File")
        .Remove("RemoveFile", "File")
        .AutoUpload(true)
        .SaveField("files")
    )

    .Events(events => events
        .Error("onError")               
        .Success("onSuccess")
    )
)
```

**On your server mvc app maybe you have FileService.UploadFile() or something similiar.**

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    ServerFileModel model = new ServerFileModel();
    try
    {
        // The Name of the Upload component is "files" 
        if (files == null || files.Count() == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("No files defined");
        HttpPostedFileBase file = files.ToArray()[0];

        if (file.ContentLength > 10485760)
            throw new ArgumentException("File cannot exceed 10MB");

        file.InputStream.Position = 0;
        Byte[] destination = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
        file.InputStream.Read(destination, 0, file.ContentLength);

        //IGNORE THIS
        ServerFileFormatEnum type = TempFileStorageController.GetFileFormatForExtension(Path.GetExtension(file.FileName));
        ServerFileDescriptor serverFile = TempFileStorageController.AddFile(destination, type);
        //IGNORE ABOVE

        model.FileIdentifier = serverFile.FileIdentifier;
        model.FileName = file.FileName;
        model.FileSize = file.ContentLength;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        model.UploadError = e.Message;
    }
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked:

It worked in following way.

```
   $("#files").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            saveUrl: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")',
            removeUrl: '@Url.Action("Remove", "Home")',
            autoUpload: false
        }

    });
```

This is how I have made a call to Kendo UI window control and it worked same way to Upload

Save is Action (Function), While Home is Controller class name